# Products.ATSuccessStory in Plone 4.1.3, Zope ConfigurationExecutionError

Tags: plone, zope

I'm trying to install Products.ATSuccessStory in a fresh Plone 4.1.3 instance on OS X Lion using Python 2.6.7. Buildout runs fine but when I try to get my instance started I get the following error:

> zope.configuration.config.ConfigurationExecutionError: : (, u'cmf.ManagePortal')
>     in:
>     File "/Users/keith/Documents/plone-sites/caches/4.1.3/Products.ATSuccessStory-4.0.0-py2.6.egg/Products/ATSuccessStory/browser/configure.zcml", line 8.5-17.11

```xml
<plone:portlet
       name="atss.rotating.portlet"
       interface=".portlets.successstory.ISuccessStoryPortlet"
       assignment=".portlets.successstory.Assignment"
       view_permission="zope2.View"
       edit_permission="cmf.ManagePortal"
       renderer=".portlets.successstory.Renderer"
       addview=".portlets.successstory.AddForm"
       editview=".portlets.successstory.EditForm"
       />
```

I'm not as in tune with zope's inner working, but as far as I know there is absolutely nothing wrong with this portlet block in the configuration. Any guidance on how I should fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from the date of its last release, the product has likely not been updated for Plone 4.1, which requires a few very minor tweaks.  These are documented at https://plone.org/documentation/manual/upgrade-guide/version/upgrading-plone-4.0-to-4.1/updating-add-on-products-for-plone-4.1/changing-dependencies-from-plone-to-products.cmfplone

Answer (score 1):

ATSuccessStory 4.1.1 has just been released that includes [the fix to this issue](http://plone.org/products/atsuccessstory/issues/5).

The source egg for this version [is available on pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.ATSuccessStory)  but not yet (eventually will be) on plone.org